# Upside down orientation is not rotating to portrait

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to view my app in all orientations, so I selected all orientaitons under `General` , then selected all orientaitons under `info.plist` in `Xcode Project Settings`

I did this is in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
}
```

and added this in `Viewcontroller`

```
func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int{
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all.rawValue)
}
```

All other orientations are working but upside down orientation.How do I get this working?

Comment: were you able to solve it? what is the answers?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to solve it and it wasn't a requirement anymore, so I didn't try it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the orientation from Xcode project settings and implement the following property in your view controller:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get { return .all } }
```

Comment: Thats what I did, and I mentioned that in my question. It is not working

Comment: If you are using swift 3 you have to implement the property exactly the way I have wrote down.
The way you implemented is completely different